# find the unit eigenvectors of matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 2 \\0 & 2 & 1\\ 0& 0 &3\end{bmatrix}

IS :

> V1=\begin{bmatrix}1  \\0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
>     V2=\begin{bmatrix}1  \\1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
>
> V3=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{2}  \\1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}

To find  unit eigenvectors I had found the magnitude of each vector(by adding them squared under a square root) and then divide each eigenvector by that magnitude

like the unite eigenvector fo V2 would be :
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\0  \end{bmatrix}

>

> is this a true way to find unit eigenvectors ????

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Yes, once you have any eigenvector, you divide by its norm to obtain a unit vector, which is still an eigenvector.

Comment: as the unit eigen of v2 would be  [1/√2, 1/√2,0] ? right